# Electron's BrowserWindow zoomFactor can be changed after construction? and how to choose nearest neighbor instead of smoothing?

Tags: node.js, electron

In node electron's [BrowserWindow constructor](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.4/api/browser-window/#new-browserwindow-options), you can specify `webPreferences: { zoomFactor: x }` to zoom the web contents of the window.

Is there a way to modify this when the BrowserWindow has already been created?

And is there a way to specify that the content is not smoothed when zoomed but rather magnified with nearest neighbor?

Comment: I am also trying to do this. Do I need to recreate the window and reload the contents?

Comment: hi! any solution on this? thanks

Comment: Nope, I haven't even touched electron again ever since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `webContents.setZoomFactor(factor)`

The zoom factor is zoom percent divided by 100, so 300% = 3.0.

[Ref.](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentssetzoomfactorfactor)

Comment: This worked for me when I called it in the "ready-to-show" event on the window.

Comment: Can verify that the key is to use a combination of `setZoomFactor` and the `ready-to-show` event.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.setZoomFactor(1.2);
  });
```

Where `mainWindow` is a `BrowserWindow`